# What are my options to debug Custom Azure policies or evaluate fields outside policy engine?

Tags: azure-policy

I am trying to build a few custom policies and I am dealing with some complex field expressions like below:

```
    "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls",
            "existenceCondition": {
                "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/ipConfigurations[*]",
                    "where": {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/ipConfigurations[*].subnet.id",
                        "like": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/*/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', first(split(field('fullName'), '/')), '/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet')]"
                    }
                },
                "equals": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

The expression does not work the way I expect. Is there any way to evaluate some of the fields or expressions mentioned above for a resource outside policy engine by making Powershell calls?

For example, when I need to debug things, how do I evaluate expressions like this outside the plolicy engine:

```
"field": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/ipConfigurations[*].subnet.id",
"like": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/*/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', first(split(field('fullName'), '/')), '/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet')]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resource Graph Query

To get current values of aliases.  I like to use a Resource Graph Query via API (Postman).  To do this, use the following endpoint with Bearer Token authorization.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2019-04-01
```

Resource Graph Query Body Payload:

```
{
    "query": "Resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network' | project aliases",
    "subscriptions": [
        "{{subscription_id}}"
    ]
}
```

UPDATE: Jan 29 2022. It looks like Alias values are no longer indexed in Resource Graph. In this case I would use the method described below.  Also you can verify the alias path you are using by running Get-AzPolicyAlias in powershell. For example,`(Get-AzPolicyAlias -NamespaceMatch 'microsoft.security' -ResourceTypeMatch 'pricings' ).Aliases` will provide a list of all aliases under the Microsoft.Security/pricings resource provider. However, they do not tell you the current value. To get the current value you can write a policy and use the method described below.

### Azure Policy Portal Feedback

Also, another good place to check for Azure Policy feedback is the `Compliance` tab of the Azure Policy portal blade. If you can get your policy to evaluate to `Non-Compliant` it will give you feedback why it has been evaluated that way.

To do this from the Policy blade

- Click `Compliance`
- Click your assignment name
- Click the applicable policy definition name
- View any `Non-Compliant` resource
- Click the ellipses `...` at the far right of the row
- Select `Compliant Reason`.

This will show you valuable nuggets of information as far as `Target Value`, `Current Value`, etc.